# Three Consecutive Binomial Coefficients in AP

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I came across an interesting pattern in the Pascal triangle, and thought I would post it as a problem here.

Given three consecutive binomial coefficients  $$\binom n{r-1},\binom nr,\binom n{r+1}$$
which are in AP, where
$$\begin{align}
\binom n{r-1}&=1\cdot 10^m+1\\
\binom nr    &=2\cdot 10^m+2\\
\binom n{r+1} &=3\cdot 10^m+3
\end{align}$$
where $m, n, r$ are integers, find $n, r$.

Comment: Hint:

$$\binom n{r-1} = \frac{1}{2}\binom n{r} = \frac{1}{3}\binom n{r+1} = 10^m+1$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well known (to those who know such things well) that $1001,2002,3003$ occur consecutively in the $14$th row of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your observation. You certainly know the Pascal triangle very well! I was hoping that someone on MSE might attempt a derivation based on the given problem statement, and in the process also identify if a solution exists for other values of $m$. Have upvoted nevertheless.

Comment: I suspect it would be a very difficult problem to find any other solutions.  But maybe somebody will be able to do it.

Comment: We'll see. But will accept your answer anyway as it's the one I had in mind. It's a surprisingly nice pattern to discover in the Pascal triangle.

Answer (score 0):

We prove the more general resukt that the system

$\dfrac{\binom{n}{r}}{\binom{n}{r-1}}=2$ Eq. 1

$\dfrac{\binom{n}{r+1}}{\binom{n}{r}}=\dfrac32$ Eq. 2

has a unique solution, which is the $\{1001,2002,3003\}$ set of binomial coefficients already identified.

To wit, from the expanded-product formula for the binomial coefficient

$\binom{n}{s}=\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n-s+1)}{(1)(2)(3)\cdot\cdot\cdot(s)}$

Eq. 1 renders

$\dfrac{n-r+1}{r}=2\implies n=3r-1$

Then Eq. 2 gives

$\dfrac{n-r}{r+1}=\dfrac{2r-1}{r+1}=\dfrac32\implies r=5$

Then $n=14$ giving the claimed result.