# Generalized Case: Three Consecutive Binomial Coefficients in AP

Tags: binomial-coefficients

This is a generalization of my earlier question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018363/three-consecutive-binomial-coefficients-in-ap) posted recently, and is a more interesting one.

Three consecutive binomial coefficients
$$\binom n{r-1},\binom nr, \binom n{r+1}$$
are in an AP (arithmetic progression) with positive common difference. Find possible pairs of $(n, r)$ where both $n, r$ are positive integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By scaling the triple we just need that:
$$ \frac{r}{n-r+1},1,\frac{n-r}{r+1} $$
are in arithmetic progression, or:
$$ r(r+1), (r+1)(n-r+1), (n-r)(n-r+1). $$
This leads to the condition:
$$ r(r+1)+(n-r)(n-r+1) = 2(r+1)(n-r+1) $$
that is equivalent to:
$$ (2r-n)^2 = n+2.\tag{1} $$
This leads to $n=a^2-2$ and $|2r-n|=a$. Assuming $r\leq\frac{n}{2}$, we get:
$$ n=a^2-2,\qquad r=\frac{n-a}{2}=\frac{a^2-a-2}{2}=\frac{(a+1)(a-2)}{2}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: Thank you. That's a very nice solution. I suppose we should also specify that $n\geq3$.

Comment: Just to point out that after the first pair, $n$ increases by $7, 9, 11, 13,...$ whilst $r$ increases by $3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...$. This is of course a result of the general formula.